# Constexpr array modification or sequential population

Tags: c++, constexpr

Im trying to create somekind of subscription list for embedded system in compile time, because it is so cool to have big dynamically generated list in ROM.

If im do it during run-time it would looks like:

```
int my_arr_size = 0;
int my_arr[10] = {};

void Subscribe(int subscriber)
{
  my_arr[my_arr_size] = subscriber;
  my_arr_size++;
}

// Somewhere deep inside code, in module 23
Subscribe(23);


// Somewhere deep inside code, in module 12
Subscribe(12);
```

But can i do something like this with constexpression? I have see no logical limitations for this.

Comment: `int my_arr[10] = {}` can't be modified at compile time after initialization. BTW, you left off a `;` Also, it should be declared `constexpr` to be initialized at compile time.

Comment: ok, but maybe there another not so straight ways?

Comment: @ReasonX: "*I have see no logical limitations for this.*" Of course you have. Your compiler doesn't let you do it in the way you're trying to do it. That's the "logical limitation". Compile-time programming, even with `constexpr`, is *largely* functional in nature. You don't get to modify external state, nor can you use externally modifiable state. You don't get to change values. Everything has to be expressed as parameters and return values to identifiable function calls. And it all has to be expressed in a single, definite order that can't be modified by linking in new code.

Comment: You have to use an initializer function, and make `my_arr` `static constexpr` respectively `static constinit` (since C++20) to request it's computed at compile-time. You can not initialize it by "call by reference" semantics or using global variables.

Comment: Typically, this is done with `__attribute__((__section__` with gcc.

Comment: @Ext3h Good points. But I'd skip the `static`.  `constexpr`will  automatically inline so you only have one instance. Might also be a good idea to use `std::array` as the size can also be established at compile time. Easier to code too.

Comment: @KamilCuk can you make a simple example as answer? That will helps me so much.

Comment: @ReasonX I found this https://gist.github.com/nickrolfe/ffc9b1c02381b9dc17c975b98db42172#file-unit-c-L75 . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50573168/how-to-collect-structs-in-an-elf-section-using-gcc-compiler-attributes has some example. I glued a small example for you with integers: https://godbolt.org/z/8j9PEY1WG . Zephyr OS also uses `__attribute__((__section__` all around to register devices statically, ex. `LOG_MODULE_REGISTER` `Z_I2C_DEVICE_STATE_DEFINE` `Z_CAN_DEVICE_STATE_DEFINE`  https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Azephyrproject-rtos%2Fzephyr%20__section__&type=code

Comment: https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/blob/b702c8e8f01f09cb73ef554b129db0773f9f98a5/include/zephyr/sys/iterable_sections.h#L188 looks like whole header from zephyr built around iterating over section elements.